# Drupal 7 - Migrate multisite setup to live server

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, migration

So I have developed a `drupal` site long ago and now I wanted new site with same `drupal 7`. So I use multisite feature to develop new site. I have created it in `staging server` and now I want to migrate the setup to live server.

**I follow following steps**

1. Export the staging server database.
2. Download all the folders of drupal via FTP.
3. Create new database on live server.
4. Import staging server database to live server.
5. Change setting.php file with new database settings, base url and domain setting.
6. Change the domain name in database domain table to live.server.com

After performing this steps, I think it should run. But my guess is wrong. It gives me blank page. Even the strange thing is if I `echo 'testing';` in `/sites/new.domain.com/template/page--front.tpl.php` its not reflecting the change.

What am I missing here? Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.
Jay Stepin.

Comment: theme directory structure should be like /sites/new.domain.com/themes/themename/template/page-front.tpl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Check if you have all modules on live server

2 - Clear all cache in database , truncate all tables who begin by "cache" (you can use drush too : drush cc all)

3 - Use drush registry rebuild (drush rr)

4 - Use drush to see logs

Comment: Yes, Thanks Fky. I got the issue. Its with registry tables. Thanks.

Comment: Great !!  it often happens ^^ so i use to clear cache and rebuild registry it prevent those errors =)